# How can i add a watermark to an image like 9gag does it

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I need to start watermarking my images as I'm starting to notice people are using them. I really don't like having watermarks all over an image.  I prefer the way 9gag does this : https://9gag.com/gag/352822

There isn't any visible watermark, however when you right click and save the image you can see the watermark. How is this done?

Comment: They have the watermark on the image but it is hidden because the container for the image isn't tall enough to show it.

Comment: I don't think that really counts as a watermark. It's just a footer.

Comment: It's just the logo concealed with css, but yeah, you can call it a watermark.

Comment: What 9gag did is that they padded the bottom of the image and then annotate it with their website's name.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a watermark is to prevent removal of attribution and/or display copyright/ownership information (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking)

What 9Gag does is so easy to subvert it's trivial. All I need to do is crop the image and remove the bottom part and voila, the image is "watermark" free (It's not really a watermark, referring to it as such to be inline with the OP's definition).

For a watermark to perform it's function, it needs to be overlayed on the image so as to prevent it's removal without damaging the image itself. What you are asking for is not watermarking at all.

Example of a watermarked image:  http://s.we.lc/UNGZeT

Comment: I completely understand your explanation of what a watermark is. I truly don't mind if someone uses my images, For me its mostly about hotlinking.

Comment: In that case, I'd look at alternatives to disallow hotlinking entirely. But if you want to use the exact same method, then you need to define what the size of the footer is, and then make sure that the div/span enclosing the image has a height = (height of image - height of footer)

Answer (score 0):

#### CSS

```
div {margin: 25px 0 0;}
div:first-child {height: 150px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0;}​
```

#### Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/J9y4G/

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided has extra space at the bottom of the image file (the actual .jpg), which contains the site's URL.  When the image is displayed on the page, it's container is shrunk so that the extra part of the URL isn't actually shown.

To replicate this, you would need to edit each of your images to add the extra info, and then re-style your images to display in a slightly smaller box.